# Linq vs. database views

Tags: database, linq, performance, view

Here’s an interesting question. Suppose we have related tables in the database, for example, Instrument and Currency. Instrument table has a currency_id field that is mapped to entry in Currency table. In Linq land what’s the better way:

a) Create Instrument and Currency entities in the DataContext and then create association or simply use join in Linq queries or

b) Create a view in the database that joins Instrument and Currency (thus resolving currency_id to currency code) and use that as an entity in Linq context?

Answer (score 1):

Would you ever use them independently?  If so, you will need to have entities for each one that will be used independently.  I suspect that you will use the Currency independently (say for a dropdown that allows you to choose a currency when creating an instrument).  That being the case, I think it would be easier to just keep them separate and have an association.

Comment: but what about performance, if i dont use view linq will do additional select for each row?

Comment: Not necessarily a LINQ expression will often resolve to a single select that will perform the required joins in SQL.

Comment: i dont think so, i used sql profiler for this case and saw that linq do select for each row :(

Comment: Interesting, if LINQ were to damage performance that badly its going to have a short lifespan.  Perhaps you should post the example in another question and ask "why is this using a select for each row instead of a single select with a join?"

Comment: Did you post the question elsewhere and if so what was the outcome and can you post the link plz? I'm wondering the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

With the ORM now abstracting the data access logic that particular function of views is no longer needed.  It would be best to leave it to the ORM since thats part of its function.

However views may still be useful to simplify stored procedures code and even for creating useful indices.

Comment: but what about performance, i saw in sql profiler that linq do additional selects for each row

Answer (score 0):

- If you load in Instrument and later use the Currencies property to load in related Currencies, there will be two queries.
- If you issue a linq query with a join, linq will convert that to sql with a join and you get all the data at once.
- If you set up a DataLoadOptions, you get all the data in one query and you do not have to write the join.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx

```
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Instrument>(i => i.Currencies)
myDataContext.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

Answer (score -1):

I find LINQ to be temperamental. I can run the same query 1 minute apart and get a different result. Note I am working of a local database so I know the data hasn't changed. Using a view with a dataset is far more reliable in my option, especially with joins.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. If you want to get feedback to your observation, please post it as question, not as answer.